# Embed node.js website in exe

Tags: node.js, express, embed, obfuscation, desktop-application

I want to build desktop application that will use **node.js** and **express** to "render" the gui in a browser.

Since the client will have access to my application, is there any easy method to embed everything in my exe ?

I don't like the idea of having so many folders in my application folder, this makes it easy for everyone to modify and steal the source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two popular solutions for delivering web-based cross-platform applications are:

- [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/)
- [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/)

I prefer NW.js because it has better backward compatibility, particularly on OS X. They have different feature sets, so you may want to play around with both to see which one meets your needs.

Comment: This looks like a very nice solution, it has even more than I need.
I am only somewhat concerned about the license.
It includes chrome and chrome has a very strange multiple license, in practice every chrome component has its own license.